# Swap IMG-SRC with another Image dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, swap

Forgive me, it's been a while since figuring out anything with jQuery, I need some guidance/help: I'd love to swap an image 00x-a for 00x-b, but not just for a single image, but for many. Once the BTN below an IMG is clicked, I'd love to swap the IMG above for 00x-b while resetting other IMGs to 00x-a.

```
<div>
    <img id="swap_this" src="img-001-a.jpg">
    <a class="button">Change-IMG</a>
</div>

<div>
    <img id="swap_this" src="img-002-a.jpg">
    <a class="button">Change-IMG</a>
</div>

<div>
    <img id="swap_this" src="img-003-a.jpg">
    <a class="button">Change-IMG</a>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(".button").click(function(){
            $("#swap_this").attr()({
                "src":"img-001-b.jpg";
            })
        })

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Only the first picture is set to img-001-a.jpg

```js
var arr = ['img-001-a.jpg', 'img-002-a.jpg', 'img-003-a.jpg']

$.each($('.swap_this'), function(index, value) {
  if(index == 0) {
     $(this).attr('src', arr[0])
     console.log($(this).attr('src'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img class="swap_this" src="img-001-b.jpg">
  <a class="button">Change-IMG</a>
</div>

<div>
  <img class="swap_this" src="img-002-b.jpg">
  <a class="button">Change-IMG</a>
</div>

<div>
  <img class="swap_this" src="img-003-b.jpg">
  <a class="button">Change-IMG</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx! This will help me get started. It seems though this "resets" all (!) IMGs to version-b (fixed by updating the ARRAY to -a). But I'd still need too add a static function for changing the one specific IMG above the BTN to ver -b… I'll keep exploring this, thx…

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it and upvote or check as answered. So I will get some points. THX

Comment: Doesn't solve what I'm trying to do though. Can you take a peak at the for-loop below, could need some help there as well? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to follow up on your answer, but ended up with something else. The below does what I need, but can it be written with "each" or using a for-loop to iterate through? Thx.

```
// clicking btn_100
$('.btn_100').click(function(e) {

    // reset all IMG to version -a.gif..
    $(".img_100").attr('src','img-100-a.gif');
    $(".img_099").attr('src','img-099-a.gif');
    $(".img_098").attr('src','img-098-a.gif');
    // set IMG_100 ver -b.gif..
    $(".img_100").attr('src','img-100-b.gif');

});

// clicking btn_099
$('.btn_099').click(function(e) {

    // reset all IMG to version -a.gif..
    $(".img_100").attr('src','img-100-a.gif');
    $(".img_099").attr('src','img-099-a.gif');
    $(".img_098").attr('src','img-098-a.gif');
    // set IMG_100 ver -b.gif..
    $(".img_099").attr('src','img-099-b.gif');

});

// and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work…

```
for(a=1; a<=100; a++) {

    // create fns for all btns
    $(".btn_" + a).click(function(e) {

        // reset all IMG to version -a.gif..
        for(i=1; i<=100; i++) {
            $(".img_" + i).attr("src","image-" + i + "-a.gif");
        }

        // set specific IMG to version -b.gif..
        $(".img_" + a).attr("src","image-" + a + "-b.gif");

    });

}
```

Comment: Still need some help: -a works fine, -b doesn't. Is that related to the nested for loops? Any ideas appreciated… Thx.

Comment: If I hardwire -b, it works; so doesn't receive and iterate var a…!?